# How to make array in jQuery with 3 columns and multiple rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I want to make this data into `jQuery` array to display on popup without submitting the form

```
Quantity  type  Item
  10      kg    Pop Corn
  40      kg    Haldi
  11      kg    Tomato
```

I want array something like this shown below

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Quantity] => 10
                [type] => kg
                [item] => Pop Corn
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Quantity] => 40
                [type] => kg
                [item] => Haldi
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [Quantity] => 11
                [type] => kg
                [item] => Tomato
            )
    )
```

Please and thanks in advance.
Thanks

Comment: you can use a json object array for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript does not support associative arrays, you'll have to make an object with it.

```
 var obj = {"0": {"quantity": 10, "type": "kg", ....}, "1": {"quantity": 10, "type": "kg", ....}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var array = [{
    quantity: 10,
    type: "kg",
    item: "pop corn"
}, {
    quantity: 40,
    type: "kg",
    item: "haldi"
}, {
    quantity: 11,
    type: "kg",
    item: "tomato"
}];

// you can access it like:
alert(array[0].item); // return pop corn
```